# Characteristic polynomial and Generating Function for recurrence relation of an integer sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Given an integer sequence, such that for $n > 2$, $a_n$ = greatest number of the form gpf $(a_{n-1})k$ + spf $(a_{n-2}) \le n^{2}$. Where gpf denotes the Greatest Prime Factor and spf the Smallest Prime Factor.

For instance: Initial conditions $a_1=2, a_2=3.$

$a_3 = 8$ (greatest number $\le 3^{2}$ of the form gpf$(3)\cdot k + $spf$(2)=3k+2$
$a_4 = 15$ (greatest number $ \le 4^{2}$ of the form gpf$(8)\cdot k + $ spf$(3)=2k+3$

How to get the characteristic polynomial? Is there a Generating Function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "characteristic polynomial" applies only to constant-coefficient linear recurrences, which yours isn't. Generating function applies to every sequence, it's just $\sum a_nx^n$, but whether it's of any *use* on a given sequence, well, that's not guaranteed.